# Webpack dependency from a module which waits for DOM loading

Tags: javascript, module, webpack

Is there a way to delay resolving dependencies from a module while it waits for some events?

For instance, there is a module globals.js which takes application user ID from the  data-attribute, creates User (from User.js) object and stores it in window to be widely used across application.

**globals.js**:

```
define('globals', ['User'], function (User) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var id = document.body.getAttribute('data-user-id')
        window.appUser = new User(id);
    });
});
```

**User.js** (just to illustrate that I want the code in globals.js to be web-packed because it has dependencies):

```
define('User', function () {
    return class User {
        constructor(id) {
            this.id = parseInt(id);
        }
    }
});
```

And **app.js** requires globals.js:

```
require(['globals'], function () {
    //window.appUser will throw ReferenceError: appUser is not defined
    //Add DOMContentLoaded listener here again? :(
});
```

It would be nice to avoid declaring DOMContentLoaded event listener in each module which is dependent on globals.js
How can I manage this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot really solve that "problem" with Webpack. It's your architecture which has the real problem here. Webpack correctly calls your callback method when your *globals* module was transfered and evaluated, but at that point, it cannot know that the module actually waits for an asynchronous event (`DOMContentLoaded`).

If you ask me, this is a prime example for a Promise object. Create a Promise in your globals module and return that Promise immediately. You then can grab that returned Promise in any module you're including *globals* and just put anything you want into the `.then()` handlers.

```
define('globals', ['User'], function (User) {
    return new Promise(function( res, rej ) {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var id = document.body.getAttribute('data-user-id')
            //window.appUser = new User(id);
            res( new User( id ) );
        });
    });
});
```

...and then go like

```
require(['globals'], function ( getUser ) {
    getUser.then(function( user ) {
        // do whatever with user object
    });
});
```

I'm not too familiar with AMD module syntax, actually using CommonJS and/or ES7 modules, but this should do the trick. It is in general a bad choice to clobber the global object with data for various reasons, so we can kill two problems at once here.

Caution: Your architecture is flawed in more ways here. We're just assuming that the `DOMContentLoaded` even has not fired because you're including the *globals* module. It would be wise to check for `document.readyState` within globals and either resolve the Promise directly or listen for the *DCL* event if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I could use Promises, but it will make using globals more complex. In my imagination it would be perfect if I could in some way return promise-like object from globals.js to be processed by module system entirely and make `require(['globals'], callback)` callback function call after that promise being resolved. Actually, I think that I'm looking for some webpack loader... Also, the actual code contains document state checking, the example is just simplified, thanks :)

Comment: Actually, the question can be treated in such way: "what it the most clean and effective way to share some data between modules, if this data is taken from the DOM".